# Bot Framework LUIS ignore specific words

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, bot-framework-composer, azure-language-understanding

I'm using Bot Framework Composer v2.1.2 and I created an intent "Cancel" with following trigger phrases:

- cancel
- quit
- abort
- exit
- never mind
- forget about it
- back

However during conversations when user is answering multiple choice questions (yes/no) LUIS also treats these answers as Cancel intents.

Is there a way to tell LUIS to **ignore** specific phrases?

I am aware that I could block interruptions for those multiple choice questions but that would impact user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing the confidence score like below?
[image: LUIS condition]

You could also create a 'None' Intent Recognized Trigger try routing the words you want to ignore to it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. For 'Yes' and 'No' LUIS is 91% (0.91) sure it should be 'cancel' so I would have to set the threshold pretty high. If I created a 'None' intent that would kick-in after selecting an answer wouldn't that just make the bot repeat the question and therefore loop? It wouldn't assign the answer to a variable.

Comment: I just tried this on the Core Assistant with Language bot and it was giving me a score of 0.48 for 'No' and so it was ignored. I guess you need to train LUIS properly. You could try the portal.

Comment: I would love to use the portal but according to official bot composer github LUIS used in Composer can't be trained in portal. It crashes. Been there, done that. I will try to operate with trigger words for now. A bit of a pain tbh.